# Can I reuse pthread_t and pthread_attr_t for new diferent thread of already executed thread consecutively?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I want to execute 2 different threads consecutively without using pthread_join, is it alright? or do i really have to declare new thread_t kind of like this:

```
pthread_create(&th,&thread_attr,shtdwn,(void*)&lpBuffer);
pthread_create(&th,&thread_attr,Run,(void*)&args);
```

And also I do not need to wait either thread to finish.
Your help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Yes it is technically ok. Though in practice it would be unusual not to keep track of each thread in case it needs to be killed or joined or any other thread operation.

Comment: Is it also valid if I would remove the first 2 argument in creating a thread? because I don't need to wait either from those thread to finish

Comment: Hold on. Are you really sure you don't ever need to `pthread_join`? At a minimum it is bad practice not to call `pthread_join` at some point as that can result in zombie threads. Also, if the threads are being created in a main thread the main thread must wait else all the threads will terminate when the main thread exits.

Comment: Yes definitely, Because I have also a way in terminating the first thread using the passed  address to the thread

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that last comment. But anyway, regarding your previous question, the [pthread_create man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) can answer them. The `pthread_attr_t` arg can be NULL if you are happy to use default attribute values but the `pthread_t`  must not be NULL.

Comment: @kaylum, that's an answer.

Comment: It is not unusual, or bad practice, to avoid join operations. In general, it is, in fact, a good thing to avoid if you can, especially with more complex apps with app-lifetime threads, thread pools and   message-driven GUIs, where premature stoptimization can result in all kinds of nasty issues when trying to close an app.

Comment: pthread_set_detachstate(&thread_attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED), removes the need for join or pthread_set_detached() within the child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the `pthread_t` and `pthread_attr_t` variables can be re-used for each `pthread_create` call. In fact, it is common for the `pthread_attr_t` to be reused like that. However, re-using a `pthread_t` variable is a bit more unusual as that value is usually stored to be used for subsequent `pthread` operations on the thread (such as `pthread_join`).

Also, the `pthread_attr_t` can be NULL in which case the default attributes will be used. However the `pthread_t` argument must not be NULL. From the [pthread_create manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html):

> The attr argument points to a pthread_attr_t structure whose contents are used at thread creation time to determine attributes for the new
>          thread; this structure is initialized using pthread_attr_init(3) and
>          related functions.  If attr is NULL, then the thread is created with
>          default attributes.
>
> Before returning, a successful call to pthread_create() stores the ID
>          of the new thread in the buffer pointed to by thread;